# Slice as a key in map

Tags: go

Is it possible to use slices as keys?

There is my attempt:

```
h := map[[]string]string{
  []string{"a", "b"} : "ab",
}
```

the compiler gives me an error `invalid map key type []string`. So either it's not possible or I declared it incorrectly (if so, what would be a correct way?).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, slices cannot be used as map keys as they have no equality defined.

Answer (score 76):

However, it is [possible](http://play.golang.org/p/Fw-49wMKFv) to use arrays as map keys:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[[2]int]bool)
    m[[2]int{1, 2}] = false
    fmt.Printf("%v", m)
}
```

Comment: Also while while a `string` can be used a as key e.g. `map[string]bool` - a byte-slice _cannot_ `map[[]byte]bool`. But a `string` and `[]byte` can be interchangeably converted - so this works:  `bs := []byte{0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef} ; mymap[string(bs)] = true`

Answer (score 22):

Volker already told that this is not possible and I will give a little bit more details of why is it so with examples from the spec.

---

[Map spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) tells you:

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands
>   of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or
>   slice.

It already tells you that the slice can't be a key, but you could have checked it also in the [comparison spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable.

---

This means that also slice can't be a key, an array can be a key. For example you can write:

```
h := map[[2]string]string{
  [2]string{"a", "b"} : "ab",
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your requirements and the complexity of your data, you could use a string as a map key and then use a hash of your slice as the map key.

The nice thing is you can use this technique with anything that can be converted to or from a slice of bytes.

Here's a quick way to convert your slice of strings into a slice of bytes:

```
[]byte(strings.Join([]string{},""))
```

Here's an example using SHA1:

```
type ByteSliceMap struct {
    buf *bytes.Buffer
    m   map[string][]byte
}

func (b *ByteSliceMap) key(buf []byte) string {
    h := sha1.New()
    h.Write(buf)
    sum := h.Sum(nil)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", sum)
}

func (t *ByteSliceMap) value(key []byte) (value []byte, ok bool) {
    value, ok = t.m[t.key(key)]
    return
}


func (t *ByteSliceMap) add(key, value []byte) {
    if t.m == nil {
        t.m = make(map[string][]byte)
    }
    t.m[t.key(key)] = value
}
```

[Working version](https://play.golang.org/p/YVPpKbHLtIx)

Comment: This is a poor choice. Even checking to see if a key exists requires load on the GC as multiple objects have to be created in order to do the lookup.

Comment: @DrewO'Meara do you have a suggestion or alternative?

Comment: This answer combines two techniques: Building short byte slice keys from long byte slices using hashing **and** converting a byte slice to a string. To convert a byte slice to a string `string(myByteSlice)` is sufficient. The conversion performs dynamic allocation (-> GC). The hashing part can be refactored in such a way that no allocation is performed (by using arrays and using e.g. Segment's fasthash).

Comment: Another problem is different string slices produce the same key.

`strings.Join([]string{"a", "b")) == strings.Join([]string{"ab"))`

Answer (score 3):

One way to get around this problem is to actually create a key from a slice which has well defined comparison operators:

```
func createKey(s []string) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%q", s) }

m := make(map[string]string)
s := []string{"a","b"}
m[createKey(s)] = "myValue"
```

In a similar fashion you would have to create functions for creating keys of slices with type different to string.

Comment: This is a poor choice.  Even checking to see if a key exists requires load on the GC since a new object has to be created in order to do the lookup.  Not cool.

Comment: Would using an int hash bypass the GC headache?