# Is it possible to define equality for named types/structs?

Tags: types, struct, go, equality

After reading a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297503/slice-as-a-key-in-map) about using slices in maps, I became curious about equality in Go.

I know it's possible to override the `equals` method of a Java `Object`. Is there a similar way to define how Go checks user defined types/structs for equality? If so, there would be a workaround for the issue referenced above. I thought using [`interface{}` values](http://play.golang.org/p/8CzhmDnDLQ) might offer a solution but I received the error message `panic: runtime error: hash of unhashable type []int`.

Comment: Not as far as I know. To work around you could convert objects to a hashable type for use in keys or even implement a hash-map from scratch using arrays. (Incidentally, some possibly-unexpected types _are_ hashable: pointers, and structs whose members are only hashable types.)

Comment: Here's the list of "comparable" types: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators -- includes channels, surprisingly!

Comment: If reading this in 2019 or later, the Equal function in github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp package looks like reflect.DeepEquals, but supports custom equality functions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**No**. You can't modify the equality operator and there is no built-in way to add support for custom types to use `==` syntax. Instead you should compare the pointer values using [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).

Go supports equality checking structs.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

a := Person{"Bill DeRose"}
b := Person{"Bill DeRose"}

a == b // true
```

It won't work with pointer fields (in the way you want) because the pointer addresses are different.

```
type Person struct {
    Friend *Person
}

a := Person{Friend: &Person{}}
b := Person{Friend: &Person{}}

a == b // false


import "reflect"

a := Person{Friend: &Person{}}
b := Person{Friend: &Person{}}

reflect.DeepEqual(a, b) // true
```

Keep in mind there are caveats.

> In general DeepEqual is a recursive relaxation of Go's == operator. However, this idea is impossible to implement without some inconsistency. Specifically, it is possible for a value to be unequal to itself, either because it is of func type (uncomparable in general) or because it is a floating-point NaN value (not equal to itself in floating-point comparison), or because it is an array, struct, or interface containing such a value.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Maybe the part "*You can't modify the equality operator and there is no built-in way to add support for custom types to use `==` syntax.*" should be marked in bold for people who read only the first sentence.

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question, the suggestion to use `reflect.deepequal` is misleading and WILL NOT WORK in many simple situations (for example: when a struct field is a map where the keys are another struct).

Comment: This answers the question in the first word!

Answer (score 28):

No, this is not user-definable. Go has strict rules what counts as equal, and even what is comparable which itself is based on assignability. Take a look at [the Comparison operators section of the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

Comment: Is there an interface or method name convention for structs which have equivalence relations other than built-in equality?

Comment: @kbolino I'm not aware of one.

Comment: The `net.IP` type has `func (ip IP) Equal(x IP) bool` which defines equivalence of IP addresses. Maybe that could be a model for such methods.

Answer (score 11):

There's no standard in Go language itself, yet (go 1.13).

However, comparison utilities could provide their own way to support it.

Function [`cmp.Equal`](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Equal) (from [google/go-cmp/cmp](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp)) supports definition of custom type comparator via definition of a Equal method:

> • If the values have an Equal method of the form `"(T) Equal(T) bool"` or `"(T) Equal(I) bool"` where `T` is assignable to `I`, then use the result of `x.Equal(y)`even if `x` or `y` is nil. Otherwise, no such method exists and evaluation proceeds to the next rule.